# Time in seconds since boot on AIX

Tags: aix, uptime

I need to get the number of seconds since the last reboot, using ksh.

What is the command or function to achieve this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/2071689 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27276 for some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Ubuntu, Redhat, Suse, we can have this file. **Not much sure about AIX, though**

See the output of:

**`cat /proc/uptime`**

If this is not available on AIX, then try to execute command ***`uptime`***

Comment: its not working on AIX 7.  

$ oslevel  

7.1.0.0  
$ cat /proc/uptime  
cat: cannot open /proc/uptime

Answer (score 1):

If you check the psinfo for process with PID 1 from /proc directory you can get this structure:

```
struct   pr_timestruc64_t pr_start; /* process start time, time since epoch */
```

Here is the [webpage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_53/com.ibm.aix.files/doc/aixfiles/proc.htm%23files-proc) you can use for reference.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is blatantly copied from Gilles' answer at [How to get a process uptime under different OS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27370/117549):

```
t=$(LC_ALL=POSIX ps -o etime= -p 1)
d=0 h=0
case $t in *-*) d=$((0 + ${t%%-*})); t=${t#*-};; esac
case $t in *:*:*) h=$((0 + ${t%%:*})); t=${t#*:};; esac
s=$((10#$d*86400 + 10#$h*3600 + 10#${t%%:*}*60 + 10#${t#*:}))
```

This leaves you with the number of seconds of uptime in `$s`.

We're making the assumption that `init`'s start time is when we start counting "uptime" and also that init is PID 1 (true in my limited testing).