# How to get server uptime of AIX server results in seconds

Tags: aix, monitoring, uptime

In Linux, I can get the server uptime results in seconds (value) by using below command

```
cat /proc/uptime
```

But in AIX, we do not have `uptime` in `/proc`. If I just type `uptime`, I get results in days, hours, minutes, but I want to get the output only in seconds like 86400 seconds or 30 seconds or any value.

With this output, I want to set an alert from SCOM monitoring tool to create alerts if it is less than 1800 seconds.

From SCOM, I can run a shell command.

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt [How to get a process uptime under different OS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27276/117549) to return the elapsed seconds of process 1 (init) as a pretty close approximation:

```
#!/bin/sh
t=$(LC_ALL=POSIX ps -o etime= -p 1)
d=0 h=0
case $t in *-*) d=$((0 + ${t%%-*})); t=${t#*-};; esac
case $t in *:*:*) h=$((0 + ${t%%:*})); t=${t#*:};; esac
s=$((10#$d*86400 + 10#$h*3600 + 10#${t%%:*}*60 + 10#${t#*:}))
printf '%d\n' "$s"
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use below one liner..

uptime=`uptime | awk -F ',' ' {print $1" "$2}'|awk ' {print $3" "$4" "$5}' | sed '1,$s/:/ /' | awk ' {if ($4 =="users") print $1*60 + $2;else if ($4 =="user") print $1*60 + $2;else if ($2=="mins") print $1;else print $1*24*60 + $3*60 + $4}'`;if [ $uptime -lt 300 ]; then echo "Rebooted before 300 minutes"; else echo "OK"; fi

Comment: Please consider reformatting your answer so that it is readable, and add an explanation of what it does.